# How to update image when darkmode is applied

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm using the useDarkMode Hook from [donavon](https://github.com/donavon/use-dark-mode)
But I'm having issues with the logo, that should update.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import useDarkMode from "use-dark-mode";

import logo_bird from "./images/green_bird.png";
import logo_font_lightMode from "./images/logo_font_black.png";
import logo_font_darkMode from "./images/logo_font_white.png";

function Navigation() {
  const darkMode = useDarkMode(false);
  return (
    <div className="nav">
      <img src={logo_bird} alt="logo_bird" />
      <img
        src={darkMode === "true" ? logo_font_darkMode : logo_font_lightMode}
        alt="logo_font"
      />
      <button onClick={darkMode.toggle}> switch </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Navigation;
```

Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useDarkMode` returns an object and not current mode in order to access the current value you need to use `darkmode.value`.

In your case:
`src={darkMode.value === "true" ? logo_font_darkMode : logo_font_lightMode}`